How to send a message if the mentioned user is not on the discord server
I am making a python discord bot and ran into a problem where I am trying to create a compliment command which sends a random compliment to the mentioned member or the command invoker. The error I am getting is because I mentioned a user in this command !compliment <username> who is not on the server, instead of sending the embeded error message in the server it gives me the terminal error as I mentioned below.
I want the bot to first check if the mentioned user is on the server or not if not then the bot will give a embeded error message to user who invoked the command.
The code is below:-
    # (4) Compliment command.
    @commands.command(
        name = 'compliment',
        aliases = ['Compliment', 'COMPLIMENT'],
        description = 'Gives a random compliment.'
    )
    async def compliment(self, ctx, *, member: discord.Member = None):
        try:
            await ctx.typing()

            response = random.choice(Compliments)

            if member is not None:
                if member.guild != ctx.guild:
                    embed = discord.Embed(
                        title = '__Error__',
                        description = 'This member is not on this server.',
                        color = discord.Color.red()
                    )
                    await ctx.reply(embed = embed)
                
                else:
                    embed = discord.Embed(
                        title = '__Compliment__',
                        description = f'{member.mention}, {response}',
                        color = discord.Color.dark_blue()
                    )
                    await ctx.reply(embed = embed)

            if member is None:
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title = '__Compliment__',
                    description = f'{ctx.author.mention}, {response}',
                    color = discord.Color.dark_blue()
                )
                await ctx.reply(embed = embed)

        except Exception as e:
            print(f'An error occurred in compliment command: {e}')

This is the error i am getting:-
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xesch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1350, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\xesch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1021, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\xesch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 938, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\xesch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 853, in _parse_arguments
    kwargs[name] = await self.transform(ctx, param, attachments)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xesch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 715, in transform
    return await run_converters(ctx, converter, argument, param)  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xesch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\converter.py", line 1355, in run_converters
    return await _actual_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xesch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\converter.py", line 1237, in _actual_conversion
    return await converter().convert(ctx, argument)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\xesch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\converter.py", line 276, in convert
    raise MemberNotFound(argument)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MemberNotFound: Member "@lakshey" not found.

Also someone already asked a similar question here but that was not working for me. So I appreciate the help on this topic.

When you define a command argument using a Discord Model like member: discord.Member, you are implicitly relating it with a converter, in this case, discord.ext.commands.MemberConverter. When a member is not found on the server, the MemberNotFound error is raised. You can attach a handler for this error to the command.
@compliment.error
async def on_compliment_error(ctx: commands.Context, error: commands.CommandError):
    # check for the error with isinstance
    if isinstance(error, commands.MemberNotFound):
        response = random.choice(Compliments)
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = '__Compliment__',
            description = f'{error.argument}, {response}',
            color = discord.Color.dark_blue()
        )
        await ctx.reply(embed=embed)
    else :
        # !! this is very important
        # without this, all errors except the ones we handled above will be IGNORDED.
        raise error

